# How can I get predefined built-in account‘s key pair from polkadotjs app? Such as Alice and Bob

Tags: polkadot, subkey

I want to use the predefined built-in account's key pair to sign extrinsic from ocw, but I can not get the key/Secret seed/Secret phrase from polkadotjs app. How can I get these items? Shall I use subkey on the node?

Answer (score 4):

All of the default substrate accounts such as `Alice` are derived from this seed:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk
```

[source](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L49).

To get `Alice`, you derive a key with a [single hard junction](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/0ba251c9388452c879bfcca425ada66f1f9bc802/primitives/core/src/crypto.rs#L754) from this key. In other words:

```
bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk//Alice
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way or function api I can use to get these information from on-chain logic or pallet code?

Comment: You can import the `DEV_PHRASE` as `use sp_core::crypto::DEV_PHRASE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use Subkey to print the Secret Key and such:

```sh
$ subkey inspect "//Alice"

Secret Key URI `//Alice` is account:
  Network ID:        substrate 
 Secret seed:       0xe5be9a5092b81bca64be81d212e7f2f9eba183bb7a90954f7b76361f6edb5c0a
  Public key (hex):  0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Account ID:        0xd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d
  Public key (SS58): 5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
  SS58 Address:      5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY
```