# Get accounts managed by dev node

Tags: account, dev-node

How to get accounts from dev node?
By default dev node start with accounts derived from mnemonic
`bottom drive obey lake curtain smoke basket hold race lonely fit walk`
As mentioned here
[How can I get predefined built-in account‘s key pair from polkadotjs app? Such as Alice and Bob](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/4487/how-can-i-get-predefined-built-in-account-s-key-pair-from-polkadotjs-app-such-a)
However you can also change those accounts (derivation path) or mnemonic.

polkadot.js.org app gets those accounts using direct storage calls.
For example Alice account is fetched by
`state.getStorage('0x5c0d1176a568c1f92944340dbfed9e9c530ebca703c85910e7164cb7d1c9e47b')`
Which more flexible solution than hardcoding mnemonic in app. However I don't know where that storage key comes from..
Any idea how to programmatically fetch all managed accounts?

EDIT:
What I'm trying to do - I want to get those accounts with RPC call.
It is possible to change those accounts in dev node (in code) and I don't want to reflect those changes in testing env. It is for sure possible cuz polkadot.js.org (using on local node) gets those accounts.
[image: accounts]

Comment: I think you need to better clarify your question. Practically speaking, a node does not have any "managed" accounts. What is exactly you are trying to do or do you want to know?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi so how it is possible that I can submit tx using those accounts without using private key (just specifying address)? That because node has knowledge about private key of that account - that is why I call it "managed".

Comment: The node does NOT have knowledge of the private key, so no. You will still need to submit a signed message which is signed externally to the blockchain.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi did you ever run dev node? I don't pass any private key to UI also it even don't ask me about private key. I just open polkadot.js.org (with local node set) and see account and can submit tx without any private key on front side.

Comment: This is because Polkadot JS detects these dev accounts, and provides them to you through the UI, not the node. Its like a global agreement that these accounts are well known in the Substrate and Polkadot community, and thus they show up everywhere.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi I see. I thought it works similar to ETH node which manage accounts and it can be accessed via RPC - especially after I noticed mentioned in question call to storage.